# Comentários em CSS com // ao invés de /* */

Tags: css, estilo-de-codificação, comentários

Colocar `//` no início de uma linha cria uma propriedade inválida, ou seja, o CSS ignora essa linha.

```
div {
    background-color: cyan;
    // background-color: red;
}
```

Sei que o padrão do CSS é utilizando `/* */`, mas qual o problema que posso encontrar utilizando dessa maneira?

Comment: Considerando a resposta do bigown, não está respondida a dúvida? Ele mostrou quais problemas podem ocorrer se você usar esse artifício, mesmo no início da linha.

Comment: Eu entendi a pergunta e a resposta foi dada para todas as pessoas que vão ler aqui. É assim que se faz um *site* de Q&A, respondemos para ajudar a todos e não só a quem pergunta. Mas se o entendimento está errado, você pode dizer o que esperava. Eu falei que é errado por que não está na especificação e pode lhe dar problema no futuro. Seu irmão :P deu um exemplo de como usar corretamente e mais alguma precaução a tomar e o bfavaretto mostro que há um caso diferente do que você postou que dá problema. Assim se constrói o conhecimento de forma colaborativa.

Comment: @bigown sim, acredito que esperei algo mais interessante de resposta, mas vi que a sua resposta pareceu ser a mais explicativa e me pareceu a mais correta também. Agradeço pela atenção dedicada. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hoje não causa problema. Mas e amanhã? Você não deve usar nada que não está na especificação justamente porque ela não é *future proof*. Se usar isto e no futuro a especificação dizer que isto serve para outra coisa ou mesmo algum navegador resolver fazer por conta própria, você está lascado e a culpa será sua.

Já vi muito software parar de funcionar quando muda a versão do sistema operacional. Quase sempre a culpa é do programador que não seguiu a especificação, ele fez o que pareceu funcionar. Funciona até o dia que não funciona mais. Aí ele fala mal do Bill Gates.

Lembre-se que estar inválido é bem diferente de determinar que a informação é apenas um comentário. Mesmo dando o mesmo resultado você está fazendo errado e poderá pagar um preço por isto. Mesmo que você não saiba qual é ele. Então nunca use algo errado.

BTW, o exemplo citado é chamado *comment out*, uma técnica que normalmente deve ser evitada, principalmente em código de produção.

[Documentação](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#comment-diagram).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

Complementando as demais respostas: esse seu exemplo não dá problema porque é no início da linha, mas no final pode dar um problemão. Por exemplo:

```
div {
    background-color: cyan;
    background-color: red; // isto não é um comentário
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Nesse caso a regra do `border` seria totalmente ignorada. Como os outros já disseram, **use os comentários conforme a especificação, ou seja, sempre `/* */`**.

Comment: Se ele queria um entendimento pra "estudos", esta resposta com certeza mostra bem o tipo de dor de cabeça +1.

Answer (score 11):

Para completar um pouco tudo o que já foi dito, e na esperança de não estar a criar nenhuma redundância de informação, o grande motivo pelo qual não podemos fugir à regra no que respeita ao desenvolvimento WEB, particularmente com HTML, CSS e JavaScript, é que o código que criamos vai ser interpretado por um navegador, navegador esse que é desenvolvimento única e exclusivamente sobre as normas criadas para cada linguagem.

Já não bastante os diversos problemas que temos com o desenvolvimento de código que se venha a comportar da mesma maneira nos diferentes navegadores, se viermos a desenvolver código que funciona por um "mero acaso", a coisa torna-se ainda mais complicada.

## Exemplos

Com base no código da tua pergunta, as `//` para sinalizar um comentário seguem 3 casos práticos, onde o primeiro é apenas para salientar a forma correta de identificar um comentário em CSS para que o navegador saiba o que fazer, sendo os outros dois exemplos uma ilustração de potenciais problemas:

#### Exemplo 01 - Uso Correto

Um cenário com comentários dentro daquilo que os [navegadores esperam receber](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments) pois a norma assim o dita, onde podemos observar diversos métodos para aplicar comentários e todos eles válidos:

```css
/* texto de aviso grave */
p {
  color: red; /* vermelho */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * A partir daqui seguem estilos para a conta do utilizador
 * -------------------------------------------------------- */
p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Super BuBu</p>
```

#### Exemplo 02 - Declaração Ignorada

Comentário de forma incorrecta que vai levar o navegador a ignorar a declaração, porque de acordo com as normas de CSS qualquer erro vai resultar na declaração ignorada.

No exemplo, o navegador vai ignorar tudo desde a `//` até ao fecho da declaração que é identificado pelo caractere `}`:

```css
// texto de aviso grave
p {
  color: red; /* vermelho */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * A partir daqui seguem estilos para a conta do utilizador
 * -------------------------------------------------------- */
p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Super BuBu</p>
```

#### Exemplo 03 - Compressão do CSS, declaração ignorada e comentário inválido fica no código resultante

Assumindo que usei um código no lado do servidor para meter o CSS todo numa só linha, código esse que também retira comentários, técnica mais conhecida por compressão.

Como no início tenho um comentário com `//`, o mesmo vai ficar no código após comprimido, e vou na mesma perder a primeira declaração, isto porque o compressor de CSS não vai recolher o `//` como a identificação de um comentário:

Se passar o CSS do exemplo #2 por esta ferramenta, [Online CSS Minifier/Compressor](http://cssminifier.com/), o resultado é o que podemos ver no exemplo em baixo:

```css
// texto de aviso grave p{color:red;text-transform:uppercase}p{font-size:2em}
```

```html
<p>Super BuBu</p>
```

Comment: +1 Excelente resposta + ótimos exemplos. +1 pela referência. O *OP* podia reconsiderar escolher essa como resposta correta.

Answer (score 10):

Comentários em CSS com `//` não existem. A sintaxe correta é usar `/* */` em todos os casos.

Comentário de uma linha:

```
body {
    /* margin: 0; */
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comentário de *n* linhas:

```
/* body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} */
```

A princípio não deve haver nenhum problema. A precaução que costuma-se tomar ao usar esse tipo de comentário é se atentar a fechar todas as tags abertas.