# Como fazer esse MENU com CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: MENU]

**HTML**

```
<nav id="menu-navigation">
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="icon building"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon services"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon portfolio"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon clients"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon testimony"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon location"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon contact"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="icon work-with-us"></span>
    <a href="#" title="">LINK UM</a>
  </li>
  <li class="logotipo">
    Imagem
  </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

**CSS (LESS) **

```
// Menu
 nav#menu-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  z-index: 4;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 118px;
    width: 1280px;
    font-size: 0px; // Espaço em Branco entre os Li's
    text-align: center;
    li {
      background-color: #7d858b;
      display: inline-block;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: none;
      line-height: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      text-align: center;
      text-indent: 0;
      padding: 0px 15px;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      transition: all 1s ease;
      &: before {
        content: none;
      }
      &:hover:not(.logotipo) {
        border-top: 1px inset #FFF;
        border-bottom: 1px inset #FFF;
        a {
          color: #ef9c2b;
        }
      }
      a {
        transition: all 1s ease;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      &.welcome,
      &.menu {
        display: none;
      }
      &.logotipo {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 118px;
        line-height: 118px;
      }
      span.icon {
        display: none;
      }
      span.pipeline {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nesse código acima, meu último **LI** é o LOGO. A barra cinza a sua direita é pra dar continuação (coloquei manualmente para mostrar o que preciso).

Eu consegui fazer o MENU até o logo. Mas preciso dessa barra cinza a direita, e tem que ser 100%, ou seja, ela deve começar dali depois da letra O de **LOGO** e terminar no canto da janela não importa a resolução.

Até coloquei uma DIV com `position:absolute` para fazer a barra cinza, mas dependendo da resolução, sobe em cima do LOGO, obviamente.

Eu não coloquei o `nav#menu-navigation` todo cinza porquê a área do LOGO é transparente, porquê tem um slider no fundo. Então a barra cinza tem que vir da esquerda parar antes do LOGO e continuar depois até o fim.

Como posso fazer ?

---

- *Meu maior problema é como fazer a barra cinza da direita que ela
  fique da direita até o logo.*
- OBS: A parte do LOGO é transparente. O `ul` não pode ter cor de fundo.
- OBS 2: Tem que ser como na imagem.

Comment: O seu `ul` tem que ser um bloco com largura 100% e a cor aplicada nele, então trabalha com os `li`'s. https://jsfiddle.net/m745hmrx/

Comment: @KaduAmaral, obrigado pela ajuda. Mas parece que você nem leu o que eu escrevi - **... a área do LOGO é transparente**. Não pode ser branco, não pode ter cor. E se colocar `transparent` ele pega a cor do `ul` que está ao fundo.

Comment: Então Diego, não tem como você fazer isso apenas com CSS. Poderia tentar utilizando javascript ou uma tabela, mas é algo que daria bastante trabalho, é muito mais fácil você setar o background do `li.logotipo` com a mesma cor de fundo do site.

Comment: Não, não é mais fácil. Na mesma linha onde está que **...a área do LOGO é transparente** continua **,porquê tem um slider no fundo.**.

Comment: Forma errada de se fazer, porém que não precisa de Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/Lybc6nf5/

Comment: Tem um kit de HTML chamado "Traingames WebKit", vem com uma barra de menu e mais 5 elementos. <a href="https://traingamesofficial.github.io/traingames.github.io/webkit.html">WebKit</a> Essa é a verção <em>free</em>, a verção <em>Professional</em> (com + de 30 elementos) tem aqui: <a href="http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-902124661-traingames-webkit-pro-_JM">Pro WebKit</a>.
Acho que verção free já está bom para o que você quer, só tenque modificar um pouquinho o stylesheet, como a fonte, background-color,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cara fiz na base da outra resposta ai do amigo que escreveu o css e o html e fiz meio de bate pronto funciona, terá que fazer os ajustes necessários mas é a solução:

```
    <style>
        nav {
           //background-color: #dddddd;
           //padding-left: 5em;
         }
         ul {           
           list-style-type: none;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           width: 393px;
         }
         li {
           padding-right: 1em;
           display: inline;
         }
         a {
           width: 100px;
         }
         .logotipo {
          // background-color: #ffffff;
           //margin: 20px;
           //padding: 20px;
         }
         .fundo{   background-color: #dddddd; float: left; }
         .fim { 
                //float: right;
               // width: 100%;
         }
 </style>    
 <script src="js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<nav id="menu-navigation">

  <ul>
    <li class="fundo" >
      <span class="icon services fu"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fundo" >
      <span class="icon portfolio"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fundo" >
      <span class="icon clients"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fundo" >
      <span class="icon location"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Location</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fundo" >
      <span class="icon contact"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="logotipo" style="float: left;">
        <a href="#" title="">Logo</a>      
    </li>    
  </ul>
    <li id="cotoco" class="fim fundo" style="float: left;">
        &nbsp;
    </li>
    <script>
        $(window).resize(function() {             
            var w = $(window).width();
            var ul_width = $('ul').width();
            var cotoco = w - ul_width - 32;
            $('#cotoco').width(cotoco);
        });
        $(window).resize();
    </script>    
</nav>
```

Comment: Cara, está me parecendo que essa é a solução. Mas não estou podendo ver esse site agora, pois estou vendo outro. Quando pegar pra fazer, volto aqui para testar sua solução. Eu joguei no JSFIDDLE e testei e funcionou perfeitamente. Fique no aguardo.

Comment: Esse -32 é o que ?

Comment: Já entendi, manolo. Obrigado. Funcionou. Eu mudei a estética do HTML e dos elementos por outros motivos. Mas entendi e apliquei sua solução. Tamanho da Janela - Tamanho do MENU - 32 - de margem do Logo é o tamanho que sobra para a faixa cinza no canto. Valeu.

Comment: @Diego esse é o ajuste que te falei, esse valor irá mudar é o width da sua logo no caso

Comment: Desculpe não comentar o código estava bem no finalzinho do expediente ;)

Comment: uahuah da nada. Percebi que você estava com pressa pelo nome da variável que você deu. **cotoco**. uahuhauha

Comment: Esses `//` eram pra ser comentários? Acho que o CSS não suporta isso, xD

Comment: @falsarella eu utilizo o netbeans a culpa é dele de não me avisar que o certo é /**/ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46229/coment%C3%A1rios-em-css-com-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de vlw por avisar

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Tranquilo.

Answer (score 1):

Criei aqui, agora você precisa mudar a cor do menu e colocar uma logo, creio que esse exemplo te da uma boa ideia [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3syhgdcs/1/)

```css
         nav {
           background-color: #dddddd;
           padding-left: 5em;
         }
         ul {
           list-style-type: none;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
         }
         li {
           padding-right: 1em;
           display: inline;
         }
         a {
           width: 100px;
         }
         .logotipo {
           background-color: #ffffff;
           margin: 20px;
           padding: 20px;
         }
```

```html
<nav id="menu-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="icon services"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="icon portfolio"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="icon clients"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="icon location"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Location</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="icon contact"></span>
      <a href="#" title="">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="logotipo">
      LOGO
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: O fundo do LOGO tem que ser transparente. Não pode ter cor.

Comment: Como eu coloquei texto e não imagem utilizei  o `background` para demonstrar a área que ficará a logo, use `background-image: url(caminhoDaimagem);` para substituir o texto pela imagem

Comment: Mas o `ul` não pode ter cor de fundo, senão não adianta a imagem ser transparente...